# unable to validate email and number

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I need help because I have added the following javascript(mentioned below in code) to my form and I am passing ID to js, but unable to validate it.

Javascript Code

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById('emailid').value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    var txt = document.getElementById('mobNo');
    var filter = /^([0]|\+91|\+91-|\+91\s)?\d{10}/;
    var test_bool = filter.test(txt.value);
    if (test_bool == false) {
        alert('Please enter valid Mobile Number ');
        txt.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Email ID" id="emailid" name="Email" required="required" maxlength="70" />
    <label class="input-field-icon icon-email" for="login-email"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobNo" name="number" required="required" maxlength="14" />
    <label class="input-field-icon icon-email" for="login-email"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Associate your javascript function with some events.

Comment: You are not calling your function at all. Please call the function on some event like onsubmit, onclick,etc according to your requirement

Comment: Your email validation logic is wrong and many invalid patterns can slip by.   Since you were already using the email input type why are you adding JavaScript to validate it? Additionally, your HTML is invalid because your labels for attribute is not pointing to the ID of the email input.

Comment: You are not using the function plus you should add these fields in form so that the validation work well :)

Comment: thank you @SuryaPurohit for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your code...

First, your HTML is not valid because your `label` elements have values for the `for` attributes that do not point to the `id` attribute values of the elements they are "for".

Additionally (and perhaps you do have it but aren't showing it in your question), you do not have a `form` element that contains all your inputs.

Now, since you are using `input type=email` and `required` in your HTML, you will get validation automatically. If you simply add the `pattern` attribute to your mobile phone filed, you won't need any JavaScript to validate as this is built-in. Using the built-in email field and then writing email validation code that validates the same way makes no sense.

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
          <!-- There's no need to set value="" on a text field when you want it to start blank -->
          <!-- When you use the HTML validation fields and attributes, you don't need JavaScript
               unless you want to implement custom validation.      -->
          <input type="email" required class="form-control" 
                 placeholder="Email ID" id="emailid" name="Email"  maxlength="70">
          <!-- The "for" attribute of a label must point to the ID of the element it is for -->
          <label class="input-field-icon icon-email" for="emailid"></label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="([0]|\+91|\+91-|\+91\s)?\d{10}" required
                 placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobNo" name="number" maxlength="14">
          <!-- You had a copy of the email label down here -->
          <label class="input-field-icon" for="mobNo"></label>
       </div>
       <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset">
       </div>
</form>
```

If you do want to write your own validation code, then you would go back to using non-validation form fields or HTML5 custom validations. Assuming that were the case...

Your validation function is not ever being called. It needs to be "wired" up to an event, so that when the event occurs, the function will automatically be invoked. That is called a "callback function". Since you are working with a `form` (or should be), the form will have a `submit` event and this is the appropriate time to do form validation.

Additionally, your email validation logic is flawed (an email address of `me.you@` would be allowed for example).

Here's what the code should look like. I have removed the HTML validation so that you can see the JavaScript doing its job.

Please read the comments in the code for explanations on what is being done and why:

```js
// Don't mix HTML and JavaScript (as others have suggested). Keep them separate

// All this code should be placed inside of a <script> element and the entire thing
// should be placed just before the end of the body element (</body>) so that by the 
// time this code runs all the HTML will have been read into memory.

// Get a reference to the elements you'll need to work with
var frm = document.querySelector("form");
var email = document.getElementById("emailid");
var mobNum = document.getElementById("mobNo");

// Set the form up to have a submit event callback function
// This is what makes it so that when your form is submitted,
// your validation function runs.
frm.addEventListener("submit", validateForm);

// This function will now be automatically called when the form is submitted
// All event handling functions will automatically be passed a reference to 
// the event they are responding to and that reference will be passed as the
// first argument to the funciton (we are receiving that reference with the
// "evt" argument here).
function validateForm(evt) {
 
  // validate the email input with a regular expression
  var emailExpr = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  
  // validate the phone number with a regular expression
  var mobNumExpr = /^([0]|\+91|\+91-|\+91\s)?\d{10}/;

  // Assume the form is valid
  var valid = true;

  // Test the input. Always call the trim() string method on user input as it
  // will strip off any leading or trailing spaces.
  if(!emailExpr.test(email.value.trim())){ 
     // Bad email.
     valid = false;
     alert("Bad email");
  }
  
  // Test to see if the email is good and the mobile is bad
  if(valid && !mobNumExpr.test(mobNum.value.trim())){
     valid = false;
     alert("Bad mobile number");
  }
  
  // If something has set the form to be invalid....
  if(!valid){
     evt.preventDefault();  // Cancel the event (don't submit the form)
     evt.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from bubbling
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <!-- There's no need to set value="" on a text field when you want it to start blank -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Email ID" id="emailid" name="Email"  maxlength="70">
      <!-- The "for" attribute of a label must point to the ID of the element it is for -->
      <label class="input-field-icon icon-email" for="emailid"></label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobNo" name="number" maxlength="14">
      <!-- You had a copy of the email label down here -->
      <label class="input-field-icon" for="mobNo"></label>
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset">
   </div>
</form>
```

Finally, no matter how you implement your client-side validation, you must always remember that it can be easily circumvented by anyone wishing to bypass it, so you should always repeat the validations on the server-side before it accepts the data.

Comment: thank you this code work fine for me. but we have to click the alert twice to make it disappear and do the changes

Comment: @PratikPurohit That's because the validation of both items is being done one after the other. I've updated the answer to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you very much @Scoot Marcus

Answer (score -1):

if you will use a form tag to validate this data you may use onsubmit attribute.

[Here is documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp)

else if you want to use a event handler for form you may pass event data and prevent it if form not valid.

[Here is some usefull information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: Do not recommend HTML event handling attributes. Instead use the standard .addEventListener() method and keep your JavaScript separate from your HTML. Additionally, W3 schools is not a great source to point others to because of its inaccuracies and sometimes outdated information. The Mozilla developer network is a much better source. Lastly, the question was not tagged with JQuery, so you should not provide links to JQuery solutions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, me too. but that's not the question

Comment: "You too", what? What is not the question?

Comment: He need to init that function that he wrote already. theres two way for that and there's two links in my answer. (I'm not recommending event handling with attributes too)

Comment: Your first link is to W3 schools where they show the in-line HTML way.  So to say that you're not recommending that way is incorrect. Your second link is to a JQuery solution,  which is also incorrect because the question was not asking for a JQuery solution.  Neither link should be used. Your answer does not show the proper way which is to use .addEventListener()

Comment: Read the question please. theres a function without any event param expecting. I'm answering that question.

Comment: Read my comments please I have explained to you that the two ways you are suggesting that the function be hooked up to the event are both incorrect. .addEventListener() is the correct answer and nothing in your post refers to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148328/discussion-between-guven-altuntas-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score -1):

You can validate user inputs easily with regular expressions. Make sure to call your JavaScript when the form is submitted.

HTML

```
<form onSubmit="myFunction()">
Email Address: <input type="email" id="userEmail" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" required>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction(){
 var email = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
 if(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)){
    alert('Valid');
 }else{
    alert('Invalid');
 }
}
```

Result

```
Input: 'email@email.com' Result: 'Valid"  
Input: 'email@email'     Result: 'Invalid'
```

Comment: Please don't advocate inline HTML event handling attributes. Also you haven't addressed cancelling the event if the validation fails.